# Android Multiple Button Handle

Tags: android, button, interface

I have created this activity with two buttons

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.content.Intent;

public class SelectOption extends Activity{

    Button bu1,bu2,bu3;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.option_main); 

    bu1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bu2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    bu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myintent1 = new Intent(SelectOption.this, CheckBalance.class);
            startActivity(myintent1);

        }
    });

    bu2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myintent2 = new Intent(SelectOption.this, CheckAvailability.class);
            startActivity(myintent2);

        }
    });
```

and there are 2 activities called CheckBalance.java and CheckAvailability.java also. but when I Run the program nothing happen on it. Does anyone have an idea what wrong with this??

Comment: Have you declare your both activities in manifest file ?

Comment: whats the prob is it when u click the activity dont start , some error or .. pls clarify

Comment: Have you addded launcher filter for your activity? DO post the Manifest.xml

Comment: @Anuradha Post your error logcat and androidmanifest.xml file of your project so we can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in  on click listener

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(); 
 intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), CheckBalance.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

and also check weather you activities declare in manifest file and in Xml also....

Answer (score 1):

This is My Manifest file (On behalf of Original question Asker(Anuradha))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.people.oshada"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TheMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >      
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SelectOption"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CheckBalance"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CheckAvailability"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: so you are at first going to TheMainActivity and you are able to navigate from there to SelectOption am i right??

Comment: Yes..MainActivity is my login..it works properly..the problem occurs on this activity

Comment: @Dasaya is there other buttons with the same id ? then such things can happen try changing the id's

Comment: There are buttons with these id's in other activity(mainActivity). U mean change those?

Comment: @Dasaya i hope you have changed the id's in corresponding activities and xml so just check wether the on click event is working by putting a toast or a log

Comment: Thanks Bro..I think that's the problem..After change those similar id's now it works. Thanks Once again..!!

Answer (score 0):

In ANDROID  MAINFEST FILE u have to add

```
<activity android:name=". CheckBalance"/>
<activity android:name=". CheckAvailability"/>
```